# error retrieving universal variables

Tags: php, mysql

i am having a problem, i am receiving an error which says  undefined variable although it was already defined, here is the snippet:

names.php

```
session_start();
$uname=$_SESSION['login'];

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name="sampledb";
$tbl_name="tblsched";
$cd = date("F d");
$cd1 = date("Y-n-d");
$ctr = 0;

// retrieving values from cookies that were created is located before this function
function mymainfunc()
{
dateto();
datefrom();
sunday();
monday();
tuesday();
thursday();
wednesday();
friday();
satday();
$arrayto = array();
$arrayfrom = array();
$arraysu=array();
$arraysa=array();
$arraym=array();
$arraytu=array();
$arrayw=array();
$arrayth=array();
$arrayf=array();

$arrayto = dateto();
$arrayfrom = datefrom();
$arraysu=sunday();
$arraysa=satday();
$arraym=monday();
$arraytu=tuesday();
$arrayw=wednesday();
$arrayth=thursday();
$arrayf=friday();

for($x=0;$x<=count($arrayto);$x++)
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align=$tdali bgcolor=$bgcolor>"+ $arrayfrom[x] + "-" + $arrayto[x] + "</td>";
echo "<td align=$tdali>" + $arraysu[x] + "</td>";
echo "<td align=$tdali>" + $arraym[x] + "</td>";
echo "<td align=$tdali>" + $arraytu[x] + "</td>";
echo "<td align=$tdali>" + $arrayw[x] + "</td>";
echo "<td align=$tdali>" + $arrayth[x] + "</td>";
echo "<td align=$tdali>" + $arrayf[x] + "</td>";
echo "<td align=$tdali>" + $arraysa[x] + "</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
}
}

//the other functions are found before this function
function dateto()
{
$sql="SELECT SchedTimeTo FROM $tbl_name WHERE teacherID=(SELECT teacherID FROM tblteacher WHERE teacherName=$uname) AND SchedDateFrom<=$cd1 AND SchedDateTo>=$cd1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$STF = array();
$STF[] = $row;
return $STF;
}
```

displayhere.php

//i inserted this snippet inside the

```
<?php
include "names.php";
mymainfunc();
?>
```

any suggestions?? the other functions didn't return any errors though

it says undefined variable tbl_name in the sql part of the function dateto()

Comment: *Where* does it say that *what* variable is undefined?

Comment: Also, read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: there,i edited my post, sorry forgot to give the error

Comment: duplicate of [php function variable scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912036/php-function-variable-scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling globally defined variables you will need to make them accessible to the function by means of the `global`keyword:

```
<?php
$my_global_var = 42;

function doSomethingImportant() {
    global $my_global_var;

    // now you can safely use that variable:
    if ($my_global_var == 42) {
        //...
    }
}
?>
```

alternatively (as explained by other answerers) you can use the `$_GLOBALS['my_global_var']`-array to acchieve the goal:

```
<?php
$_GLOBALS['my_global_var'] = 42;

function doSomethingImportant() {

    // now you can safely use that variable:
    if ($_GLOBALS['my_global_var'] == 42) {
        //...
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That's not exactly true, there are several other ways to get the value into the function.

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly declare variable as global to ensure it's scope:

```
//the other functions are found before this function
function dateto()
{
    global $tbl_name;
    global $uname;
    //Add all you global-scoped variables
    $sql="SELECT SchedTimeTo FROM $tbl_name WHERE teacherID=(SELECT teacherID FROM  tblteacher WHERE teacherName=$uname) AND SchedDateFrom<=$cd1 AND SchedDateTo>=$cd1";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $STF = array();
    $STF[] = $row;
    return $STF;
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly true, you're not required to use globals, infact, it's generally frowned upon.

Comment: Nontheless using globals is a valid approach.

Comment: Yeah, just the rhetoric implies that it's the only way.

Comment: @KorvinSzanto : I'm not telling that it's only way in universe, I just propose solution.

Comment: @rkosegi, "should" is better than "must", it implies that he has a choice while must does the opposite. None-the-less, it's not wrong, have an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a global variable within function scope, check out the second example on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

You can move `$tbl_name = ..` to the function, or put `global $tbl_name;` in just before the sql statement, or you can use `$_GLOBALS['tbl_name']` instead of $tbl_name.