# PHP global variables not working inside a function

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php function variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912036/php-function-variable-scope)

I am using below code to test with a global variable. It seems that a global variable cannot be compared inside a function.

Why is it not displaying 'hello world' in the output?

Below is the code that I am trying:

```
<?php    
$bool = 1;

function boo() {
    if ($bool == 1) {
        $bool = 2;
        echo 'Hello World';    
    }
}
?>
```

When I remove `function boo()`, 'hello world' is displayed. Why is it not displaying when function exists?

Comment: Where are you calling your function?

Comment: `$bool` is not defined in the function scope. You need to access it globally, or better, pass it to the function.

Comment: You never actually call the function. Then, even if you were, you wouldn't see your 'Hello Word' printed, because `$bool` doesn't exists in the function scope.

Comment: $bool is a Global variable, Right? so it should be accessed within function as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like homework, still:

```
<?php

$bool = 1;

boo();

function boo() {
global $bool;

if ($bool == 1) {
$bool = 2;
echo 'Hello World';

}


}
?>
```

Or

```
<?php

$bool = 1;

boo(&$bool);

function boo(&$bool) {

if ($bool == 1) {
$bool = 2;
echo 'Hello World';

}


}
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

use `global $var` to access your variable

```
<?php    
$bool = 1;

function boo() {
    global $bool;
    if ($bool == 1) {
        $bool = 2;
        echo 'Hello World';    
    }
}

boo();
?>
```

Or a safer way using pointers would be to

```
function boo(&$bool) {
    if ($bool == 1) {
        $bool = 2;
        echo 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using globals, even if the OP asks for it.

Answer (score 3):

Call you function, and pass `$bool` as a parameter and return the value.

```
$bool = 1;
$bool = boo($bool);

function boo($bool) {

  if ($bool == 1) {
    $bool = 2;
    echo 'Hello World';    
  }

  return $bool;
}
```

Comment: you don't actually set the value of bool here to the global value - see my answer for the correct solution.

Comment: @OliverAtkinson You are right! I didn't realize the `$bool` was being updated, I just considered the `Hello World`.

Answer (score 0):

use this way

```
$bool = 1;
function boo($bool) {

  if ($bool == 1) {
    $bool = 2;
    echo 'Hello World';    
  }
}
boo($bool);
```