# php variables inside functions vs outside

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php function variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912036/php-function-variable-scope)

is there any reason i can't push these variables in the function?
if i do this

```
//function scraping_for_text_2
for($i=0; $i<$l; $i++) { 
echo "$contents[$i]";
echo "$fnamearray[$i].torrent";
}
```

it echoes back the correct vaules

but when i have an function like this

```
function scraping_for_text_2($iUrl,$iText)

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $uploadurl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$curlresult = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
                      $data = array( 

"description" => "testing",
"torrent" => "@$fnamearray[$i]",
"submit" => "Upload"
);
```

i get this
Notice: Undefined variable: fnamearray 
Notice: Undefined variable: i in

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: pass them as arguments into your function! you can also access them via the `globals` or `$GLOBALS` but i wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: It is called [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).  It is good.  You can abuse it with things like global's but should not.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to learn basic concepts such as [variable scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) before getting too involved in any programming language.

In this case, your variables simply aren't defined inside the function.