# XAMPP unidentified variable notice

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I keep on getting this error:

Notice: Undefined variable: var1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Series\DieOrExit.php on line 7

even though my syntax is correct, $var1 is a global variable, and I'm calling $var1 within my function. I tried to turn off notices by going to php.ini and setting my error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE and restarting Apache but nothing happens. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this problem? Thanks!

Here is my script:

```
<?php

$var1 = "hello";

function x()
{
    echo $var1;
}

x();
?>
```

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912036/php-function-variable-scope

Answer (score 1):

That happends, because variable inside your `x()` function has only local scope.

See [Variable scope at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

There is an almost identical example:

```
<?php 

$a = 1; /* global scope */ 

function test() 
{ 
    echo $a; /* reference to local scope variable */  
} 

test(); 
?>
```

With description:

> This script will not produce any output because the echo statement
>   refers to a local version of the $a variable, and it has not been
>   assigned a value within this scope. You may notice that this is a
>   little bit different from the C language in that global variables in C
>   are automatically available to functions unless specifically
>   overridden by a local definition. This can cause some problems in that
>   people may inadvertently change a global variable. In PHP global
>   variables must be declared global inside a function if they are going
>   to be used in that function.

---

To workaround this, you have to pass your variable to function, like this:

```
<?php

$var1 = "hello";

function x($var2)
{
    echo $var2;
}

x($var1);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting scope of $var1 as global scope with global keyword like this inside the function

```
// error_reporting(E_ALL);
$var1 = "hello";

function x()
{
    global $var1;
    echo $var1;
}
x();
```

you need to declare variable as global inside function as shown, then you can use $val inside function.