# PHP Undefined variable: array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, undefined

I need to check whether selected city ( $_GET['city'] ) behaves in $cities array or not. Right now i'm getting errors "Undefined variable: cities" and "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". If i check $cities with is_array it returns true. How can i fix my code?

```
$cities = array ("London" => "name/name2/name3", 
"Paris" => "name/name3/name4", 
"Moscow" => "name/name5/name6", 
"Paraguay" => "name/name4/name5");



function CityIsCorrect() {                                                                  //IN WORK
        if (empty($_GET['city'])) {return false;}
        foreach ($cities as $citycheck){
            if(($_GET['city'])==$citycheck) {return true;}
            else {return false;}
        }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php function variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912036/php-function-variable-scope)

Comment: Hi, it is related to scope, in PHP a function block code doesn't know/have access to the variables outside its block, so `$cities` is undefined inside `CityIsCorrect()` function. You would need to add a parameter `$cities` to the function and pass the variable `$cities` when calling the function.

Comment: Thanks, it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question – add this line to your function:

> `global $cities`

By default, all variables within a `function` are "local."  If you want to refer to a global function *(a variable declared outside of any function-block)*, you must use `global`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445972/stop-using-global-in-php